# Problem with integration Springboot - Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

I am trying to create a sample application to connect Spring boot with Keycloak.
This is my clients application called

[Clients application keycloak](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAYrz.png)

This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ibm.test.keycloak</groupId>
<artifactId>KeyCloakTest</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.keycloak/keycloak-spring-security-adapter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-security-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

this is my main class

```
package com.ibm.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication 
public class KeyCloakApplication  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       SpringApplication.run(KeyCloakApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and my two configuration class

```
package com.ibm.test;

import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.KeycloakConfiguration;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.authentication.KeycloakAuthenticationProvider;
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;   
import org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.management.HttpSessionManager;   
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;   
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnMissingBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.SimpleAuthorityMapper;
import org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.SessionAuthenticationStrategy;

 @KeycloakConfiguration
 public class SecurityConfig extends KeycloakWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
@Override
public SessionAuthenticationStrategy sessionAuthenticationStrategy() {
    return new RegisterSessionAuthenticationStrategy(new SessionRegistryImpl());
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    SimpleAuthorityMapper grantedAuthorityMapper = new SimpleAuthorityMapper();
    grantedAuthorityMapper.setPrefix("ROLE_");

    KeycloakAuthenticationProvider keycloakAuthenticationProvider = keycloakAuthenticationProvider();
    keycloakAuthenticationProvider.setGrantedAuthoritiesMapper(grantedAuthorityMapper);
    auth.authenticationProvider(keycloakAuthenticationProvider);
}

@Bean
@Override
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(HttpSessionManager.class)
protected HttpSessionManager httpSessionManager() {
    return new HttpSessionManager();
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    super.configure(http);
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/greet").hasRole("user")
            .anyRequest().permitAll();
}
```

}

and the other one

```
package com.ibm.test;

import org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class KeycloakConfig {

    @Bean
    public KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
        return new KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver();
    }
}
```

This is a simple `RestController` used to test my application

```
package com.ibm.test;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

 @RestController
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/greet")
    public String helloWorld(){
        return "Hello World from Keycloak!";
    }

    @GetMapping("")
    public String helloWorldHomepage(){
       return "Hello Word";
    }
}
```

And finally this is my `application.properties` file, where I stored all the information about keycloak

```
keycloak.auth-server-url=http://192.168.133.129:8080/auth/
keycloak.realm=test_keycloak
keycloak.resource=appId
keycloak.public-client=true
keycloak.enabled=false
```

The application starts, but when I try to access `http://localhost:8080/greet` I get a 500 Internal Server Error. This is the Stacktrace:

```
2020-05-21 15:15:04.566 ERROR 2180 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing /

java.lang.RuntimeException: Must set 'realm' in config
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.internalBuild(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:57) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.1.jar:10.0.1]
at org.keycloak.adapters.KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.java:202) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.1.jar:10.0.1]
at    org.keycloak.adapters.springboot.KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.resolve(KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver.java:39) ~[keycloak-spring-boot-adapter-core-10.0.1.jar:10.0.1]
at org.keycloak.adapters.springsecurity.config.KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.resolve(KeycloakSpringConfigResolverWrapper.java:40) ~[keycloak-spring-security-adapter-10.0.1.jar:10.0.1]
at org.keycloak.adapters.AdapterDeploymentContext.resolveDeployment(AdapterDeploymentContext.java:89) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.1.jar:10.0.1]
at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.preflightCors(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:100) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.1.jar:10.0.1]
at org.keycloak.adapters.PreAuthActionsHandler.handleRequest(PreAuthActionsHandler.java:75) ~[keycloak-adapter-core-10.0.1.jar:10.0.1]
at org.keycloak.adapters.tomcat.AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.invoke(AbstractKeycloakAuthenticatorValve.java:177) ~[spring-boot-container-bundle-10.0.1.jar:10.0.1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1594) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_221]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_221]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.33.jar:9.0.33]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_221]
```

UPDATE:

these are all the classes/files in my project

[Three project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fY5kM.png)

Comment: May it be a problem with your Spring Boot configuration file format? Try spacing: `keycloak.realm = test_keycloak`

Comment: Just tried but I get the same error..

Comment: Is the application.properties file located in the 'resources' folder within the project?

Comment: Yes...I updated my question and now you can see the structure of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem moving the file `application.properties` on the parent directory.
Now this is the structure of the project

[Structure of the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZGKP.png)